# How to decrypt SSL data on a considered-to-be-compromised host?

Tags: tls

I have a package which I want to encrypt on my machine and send it to another remote machine. If I use asymmetric encryption, I must have the private key on the remote side. However, I don't trust the remote side from messing up with my key and encrypt the data by themselves. How can I prevent this from happening?